# Suppressing section name in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to have a TOC like so:

```
Name of part
Name of Chapter
  Section 1 ..... page
  Section 2 ..... page
```

I don't want the section's name to appear anywhere in the TOC.  I want it hidden.

I've tried redefining `\l@section` like so

```
\let\latexl@section\l@section
\def\l@section#1#2{\begingroup\numberline{#1}\latexl@section{}{#2}\endgroup}
```

but the issue seems to be that \section calls addtocontents with the line number and the line name information packed into the same call to numberline...  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your posting correctly, you've already created the code that will prefix "section" to the entries in the table of contents. To suppress the listing of a section *header* and only show the "section" prefix and the number, you could provide the instruction `\null` as the optional argument of the `\section` macro, as is done in the example below. Note that I haven't provided any code to prefix the string "Section" in the example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\section[\null]{Second section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that defines an alternate `\tableofcontents` command called `\tableofcontentsssn` (table of contents with separate section numbers), so you can have both styles of table of contents in the same document if you like. You can configure `\lssn@section` and the like to show the number and the name separately; they take three arguments, the section number, the section name and the page number. Parts work differently, because `\l@part` hard-codes the part number in the next instead of using `\numberline`, so the first argument to `\lssn@section` is always empty.

If you want to redefine `\tableofcontents` instead of having an alternative command, what matters is to change the definition of `\contentsline` while processing the toc entries.

I've only tested this code with the `report` class. Given that I use several dirty tricks it probably fails with some classes or packages. Merely including `titlesec` doesn't break it but I haven't tested it further.

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter

%% \tableofcontentsssn and supporting commands
\newcommand{\contentsline@ssn}[2]{%
  \contentsline@ssn@{#1}#2\endcontentsline%
}
\def\contentsline@ssn@#1{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\contentsline@ssn@command\expandafter{\csname lssn@#1\endcsname}%
  \futurelet\contentsline@ssn@next\contentsline@ssn@@%
}
\def\contentsline@ssn@@{%
  \ifx\contentsline@ssn@next\numberline%
    \expandafter\contentsline@ssn@numberline%
  \else%
    \expandafter\contentsline@ssn@classic%
  \fi
}
\def\contentsline@ssn@numberline\numberline#1#2\endcontentsline{%
  \contentsline@ssn@command{#1}{#2}%
}
\def\contentsline@ssn@classic#1\endcontentsline{\contentsline@ssn@command{}{#1}}
\newcommand{\tableofcontentsssn}{%
  \begingroup%
  %\@fileswfalse % if you want the next \tableofcontents to show the same contents
  \let\contentsline\contentsline@ssn%
  \tableofcontents%
  \endgroup%
}

%% Formatting for \tableofcontentsssn entries
\newcommand*{\lssn@part}[3]{\l@part{#2}{}}
\newcommand*{\lssn@chapter}[3]{\l@chapter{\numberline{#1}#2}{}}
\newcommand*{\lssn@section}[2]{\l@section{Section \numberline{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\lssn@subsection}[2]{\l@section{Subsection \numberline{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\lssn@subsubsection}[2]{\l@section{Subsubsection \numberline{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\lssn@paragraph}[2]{\l@section{Paragraph \numberline{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\lssn@subparagraph}[2]{\l@section{Subparagraph \numberline{#1}}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontentsssn
\part{Party of the first part}
\chapter{Name of chapter}
\section{First}
\section{Second}
\end{document}
```